# Basic Python while/for question. Can't break out of a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Every function is working but can't quite get out of this whole function. even though I use break, something is not working. help, please.

```
def start():
    wizard = "Wizard"
   elf = "Elf"   
   human = "Human"
   orc = "Orc"

   wizard_hp = 70
   elf_hp = 100
   human_hp = 150
   orc_hp = 400

   wizard_damage = 150
   elf_damage = 100
   human_damage = 20
   orc_damage = 200

   dragon_hp = 300
   dragon_damage = 50

   while True:
  
       print("✰✰ Welcome to the game ✰✰\n")
       print("1)   Wizard ")
       print("2)   Elf ")
       print("3)   Human ")
       print("4)   Orc ")

       character = input("Choose your character: ").lower()

       if character == "1" or character == "wizard":
           character = wizard
           my_hp = wizard_hp
           my_damage = wizard_damage
           break
       elif character == "2" or character == "elf":
           character = elf
           my_hp = elf_hp
           my_damage = elf_damage
           break
       elif character == "3" or character == "human":
           character = human
           my_hp = human_hp
           my_damage = human_damage
           break
       elif character == "4" or character == "orc":
           character = orc
           my_hp = orc_hp
           my_damage = orc_damage
           break
       else:
           print("\n- Unknown Character \n")
       break

   print("\nYou have chosen the character: ", character)
   print("\n- Health: ", my_hp)
   print("- Damage: ", my_damage, "\n")

   while True:
  
       dragon_hp =- my_damage
       print("The", character, "damaged the Dragon!")
       print(f"The {character}'s hitpoints are now: {my_hp} \n")
       if dragon_hp <= 0:
           print("The Dragon has lost the battle", "\n")
      
       my_hp =- dragon_damage
       print("The Dragon strikes back at", character)
       print("The Dragon's hitpoints are now: ", dragon_hp, "\n")
       if my_hp <= 0:
           print("You have lost your battle! ", "\n")
    
       play_again = input("Do you want to play again? Type Yes or No: ").lower()
  
       while True:
         if play_again == "1" or "yes":
             print("\n") # even if you only put start(); on line 80, the line 81 and 83 is reading line 80(start(;)) for some reasons
             start();   
         elif play_again == "2" or "no":
             break
         else:
             break
       break   
start();
```

This is just basic python stuff that I'm trying to get started. I know I'm missing a small thing but quiet cannot get to the result.

On the very last while loop, It has Its comment in it. please read it for an additional explanation

Comment: Why do you have semicolons? It's Python

Comment: Function calls are not `goto`. Either use recursion to implement your game loop *or* use a `while` loop. Do not do both.

Comment: Right.  The whole section from `play_again` to the end should be OUTSIDE the function.  `start()` should run once and exit.

Comment: Hey Ian, feel free to take a look at my comment, you're definitely close but you have a few things missing.

Answer (score 1):

Two separate things:

1. Your logic at the very end is actually always `True` because you forgot to add `or play_again == "yes`.
2. Right now your game asks if the user wants to play again after every single turn. Your check to play again should be tabbed in, so that it only executes **one** time after the game is played, not after each time.

---

When you're comparing statements, Python will attempt to make your values booleans. So, it will execute `bool(insert-statement-here)`. So, at the very end, your comparison, `if play_again == "1" or "yes":` is actually two parts.

`bool(if play_again == "1")` - this has a value. It depends on if they put in play_again.

`bool("yes")` - this is ALWAYS true. Since this is always true, your code will always enter this block.

---

Your head is in the right place, you should do:

```
if play_again == "1" or play_again == "yes":
    print("\n")  # even if you only put start(); on line 80, the line 81 and 83 is reading line 80(start(;)) for some reasons
elif play_again == "2" or play_again == "no":
    break
else:
    break
```

---

I think you're displaying the health backwards as well. After the dragon strikes, you should display the character's health, not the dragon's. This is a long answer, but I think it resolves several of the issues you're encountering. You are definitely very close, but try to slow down just a bit. *Your code will only be as clear as your thoughts on the problem - not more.* You only need the playing of the game to be on a while true, everything else is just configuration, which can be done up front when the game starts. The "playing of the game" - which is the "damaging going back and forth" is the only thing that needs to be in the while.

```
def start():
    wizard = "Wizard"
    elf = "Elf"
    human = "Human"
    orc = "Orc"

    wizard_hp = 70
    elf_hp = 100
    human_hp = 150
    orc_hp = 400

    wizard_damage = 150
    elf_damage = 100
    human_damage = 20
    orc_damage = 200

    dragon_hp = 300
    dragon_damage = 50

    print("✰✰ Welcome to the game ✰✰\n")
    print("1)   Wizard ")
    print("2)   Elf ")
    print("3)   Human ")
    print("4)   Orc ")

    character = input("Choose your character: ").lower()

    if character == "1" or character == "wizard":
        character = wizard
        my_hp = wizard_hp
        my_damage = wizard_damage
    elif character == "2" or character == "elf":
        character = elf
        my_hp = elf_hp
        my_damage = elf_damage
    elif character == "3" or character == "human":
        character = human
        my_hp = human_hp
        my_damage = human_damage
    elif character == "4" or character == "orc":
        character = orc
        my_hp = orc_hp
        my_damage = orc_damage
    else:
        print("\n- Unknown Character \n")
        return

    print("\nYou have chosen the character: ", character)
    print("\n- Health: ", my_hp)
    print("- Damage: ", my_damage, "\n")

    while True:

        dragon_hp -= my_damage
        print("The", character, "damaged the Dragon!")
        print("The Dragon's hitpoints are now: ", dragon_hp, "\n")
        if dragon_hp <= 0:
            print("The Dragon has lost the battle", "\n")
            play_again = input("Do you want to play again? Type Yes or No: ").lower()
            break

        my_hp -= dragon_damage
        print("The Dragon strikes back at", character)
        print(f"The {character}'s hitpoints are now: {my_hp} \n")
        if my_hp <= 0:
            print("You have lost your battle! ", "\n")
            play_again = input("Do you want to play again? Type Yes or No: ").lower()
            break

    if play_again == "1" or play_again == "yes":
        print(
            "\n")  # even if you only put start(); on line 80, the line 81 and 83 is reading line 80(start(;)) for some reasons
        start()



start()
```